# request parameter using jquery/javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

is it possible to stop the submission of a form,after submit button has been clicked and get the action attribute and the request parameters of the submission using javascript(preferably jQuery) ?
I want to get the action and the parameter so that the it can be submitted to an alternate location ,what i am tryin to do is try writing a proxy website.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Can't you just concatenate the form's action with a [serialization](http://api.jquery.com/serialize/) of the form's data, e.g.:

```
$('form').submit(function() {
  alert($(this).attr("action") + $(this).serialize());
  return false;
});
```

Comment: how can i get the post parameters ?

Comment: @Bunny Rabbit - `serialize()` will serialize all of the form's elements the same way regardless of the form's method.